# Calculate upper left corner of a fixed ratio, centered image in a dynamically resize-able box

Tags: geometry

I have an image with a certain aspect ratio, say $r = \frac{400}{300}.$

The image is placed in a dynamically resize-able window (on a computer screen). The image is automatically  resized and positioned inside this window, when the window is resized. The image always keeps its aspect ratio, and it is always centered. In addition, the image always extend itself to the windows max width or height, depending on which one to fit, at any one moment.

My question is, how can I calculate the upper left corner of the image, in window coordinates. The windows upper left corner is (0,0) and lower right is (height, width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Image and Screen]

The sketch shows an image ($h_{i}$ height and $w_{i}$ width), which is placed right in the middle of a dynamically resizing screen ($h_s$ height and $w_s$ width). The image automatically adjusts itself to fit the screen while keeping its aspect ratio constant.

The expression $\mathbf{aspect\space ratio}$ is used in this answer to denotes the fraction $\frac{\mathrm{height}}{\mathrm{width}}$. Therefore, the aspect ratios of the image and the screen $\alpha_i $ and $\alpha_s$ are given by,
$$\alpha_i = \frac{h_i}{w_i}\quad  \mathrm{and}\quad \alpha_s = \frac{h_s}{w_s}.$$
$\alpha_i$ is a constant, while $\alpha_s$ varies with each resizing of the screen. In general, a resizing of the screen can results in one of the three different scenarios depicted in the sketch given above depending on the magnitude of the current aspect ratio of the screen relative to that of the image. Please note that $C_{ul}$ indicates the upper-left corner of the image.

In the first case, where we have $\alpha_s \lt \alpha_i$, only the height of the image can be adjusted to fit the screen. If we try to adjust the width of the image to fit the screen, parts from the top and/or bottom of the image will be cropped and, as a result, its aspect ratio will be changed. Therefore, the height $h_i$ of the adjusted image is equal to $h_s$ and its new width $w_i$ is given by,
$$w_i = \frac{h_s}{\alpha_i} \lt w_s.$$
This leaves two rectangular areas, each having a width of
$$\frac{w_s – w_i}{2}=\frac{w_s – \frac{h_s}{\alpha_i}}{2}=\frac{\alpha_i w_s – h_s }{2\alpha_i },$$
blank to the left and right of the image. Therefore, the upper-left corner of the image in current-screen’s coordinates can be written as,
$$C_{ul} = \left(\frac{\alpha_i w_s – h_s }{2\alpha_i },\space\space 0\right). \tag{1}$$

The second case arises if $\alpha_s \gt \alpha_i$, where the width of the image can be adjusted to fit the screen. Any attempt to adjust the height of the image to fit the screen will crop parts from the left and/or right of the image leading to a change in its aspect ratio. The width of the adjusted image $w_i$ is equal to the that of the current screen, i.e. $w_s$. Consequently, the new height of the image is given by,
$$h_i = \alpha_i w_s \lt h_s.$$
This leaves two rectangular areas, each having a height of
$$\frac{h_s – h_i}{2}=\frac{h_s – \alpha_i w_s}{2},$$
blank to the top and right of the image. Therefore, the upper-left corner of the image in current-screen’s coordinates can be expressed as,
$$C_{ul} = \left(0, \space \frac{h_s – \alpha_i w_s}{2}\right). \tag{2}$$

The third case turns up if the aspect ratios of the image and the current screen are equal. It is easy to see that the image fills the entire screen in this instance. Therefore, the upper-left corner of the resized image coincides with that of the current screen, i.e.
$$C_{ul} = \left(0, \space 0\right). \tag{3}$$

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Comment: Pleasure is mine!